# How to edit videos keeping existing geotagging?

Tags: iphone, video, imovie, gps

Videos recorded with an iPhone or with other GPS-enabled phones gets geotagged as they should. When I trim/crop/edit them in iMovie (iLife '09) the GPS tags are gone.

How to keep the tags despite editing or is there a program to add back the geotags to the movie afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You can geotag videos with [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/mac/), but I don't know if the geotag is saved along with the file...

Answer (score 1):

You can download the free app [GeoCam Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/geocam-free/id435668911?mt=8) in the App Store. This app allows you to upload the video to the site veryminute.com and add the video to your  iPhone's library. I think the tags will be also synced.